# Where can I find my blog page?

Tags: blog

I recently learned about the differences between `home.php`, `front-page.php`, and `index.php`. I rightly created a `front-page.php` to handle the Landing page, a `home.php` to handle the blog (posts list) and an `index.php` to manage the other paths.

So far, the `front-page.php` is handling the landing page and I expect the home.php to handle the `/blog` path. But when I go to the `/blog` path, it uses the `404.php` template and tells me "page not found".

I learned I could make the `/blog` path work by creating a static page called `blog` and assign the `post` page to show the blog page (settings >> reading), but I think this is too crude and do users need to do this themselves?

So I'm confused at the moment and would need your help.

How can I make my `/blog` path work?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you need to do. The `home.php` file is used if you're using the main page of your site to display posts or if you have created a separate static page - your Blog page in this case. Perhaps you find it crude but it's perfectly normal to do this.

If you don't change the reading settings, the main page of your site will show your list of posts (more of a traditional blog).

Have a look at the [Template Hierarchy documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) as this goes into more detail - specifically the [Home Page display](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. 

Just to be clear, if I was developing a Wordpress theme, I would normally make the `home.php` template automatically answer the `/blog` path and the `front-page.php` answer the root of the site.

But for the user to make this work, they would need to create a `blog` static page?

Comment: That is basically correct. The other option would be to implement a check for your theme being activated, and at that point you can check for an existing blog page, otherwise create a new page. You can then use [update_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) to set `page_for_posts` / `page_on_front`. I'd just leave it to let the user create the page as it's a common thing to do. Good luck with your new theme and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. For some reason, I can't upvote this answer.

Comment: You should be able to accept my answer, but up/down voting on the site needs you to have a bit more reputation (post and answer more questions).